# He fell over himself to be/for being

Tags: grammar

Do these sentences have the same meaning? If they haven't, please explain why.

1. He fell over himself **to be** as helpful as possible.
2. He fell over himself **for being** as helpful as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. He fell over himself to be as helpful as possible. = He fell over himself **in order** to be as helpful as possible.
2. He fell over himself for being as helpful as possible. = He fell over himself **because he had been** as helpful as possible.

The second one does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks ever so much @Greybeard